# Want to transfer huge amount of data form one machine to other machine using JMS

Tags: jboss, jms

I have one web application is running on Jboss 5 and want to run same application on other machine  and it will transfer tens of millions records per day. I am planning for JBoss JMS. Please let us know, will it be a good option or there are some other better options.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe XML would help. 
Based on my experience, it is not efficient to do it db to db since it is a slow process due to network latency and since there is no multithreading.
I managed to solve my problems with files and queries using offsets.